# Salesforce custom object and attachments

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex

Ok, I've been tasked with creating a custom salesforce object that saves some data. That's the easy part.

Where I'm struggling is adding a piece to upload files associated with the record created in the custom object.

The custom object is essentially a form with fields on it. But I also need to upload relevant files.

So I built the form part of the custom object. I used an Apex class and a VisualForce page for the "upload" part.

Unfortunately, in the course of testing, I keep getting errors on the VisualForce/Apex piece.

The errors I get are the following:

Parent: Parent ID: id value of incorrect type: 00590000000yBOmAAM

And my Apex class looks like this:

```
    public with sharing class FileToDocument {
    public Attachment attachment{
        get{
            if(attachment == null)
                attachment = new Attachment();
            return attachment;
        }
        set;
    }           

    public PageReference upload(){
        attachment.OwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId();
        attachment.ParentId = '00590000000yBOm';
        attachment.IsPrivate = false;

        try{
            insert attachment;
        }
        catch(DMLException e){
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR, 'Error Uploading Attachment'));
            return null;
        }
        finally{
            attachment = new Attachment();
        }

        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.INFO, 'Attachment Uploaded Successfully'));

        return null;
    }
}
```

I am very much a novice at SalesForce. I think the problem is the ParentID line, but I don't know exactly how to fix it.

What I'm trying to do is to be able to upload/attach documents to a record, while I'm filling out the form for the record.

My VisualForce looks like this:

```
<apex:page controller="FileToDocument">
    <apex:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <apex:pageMessages />
        <apex:pageblock >
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton action="{!upload}" value="Attach"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>

            <apex:pageBlockSection showHeader="false" columns="2" id="block1">
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                    <apex:outputLabel value="File Name" for="fileName"/>
                    <apex:inputText value="{!attachment.name}" id="fileName"/>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                    <apex:outputLabel value="File" for="file"/>
                    <apex:inputFile value="{!attachment.body}" filename="{!attachment.name}" id="file"/>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

So what could I be doing wrong? My other thought is that there's simply no way to upload appropriate files until after the record has been created. Even then, I think I'd still need to know how to associate it with the Parent ID.

Any help is greatly appreciated, as always.

Answer (score -1):

This is no longer relevant. The project was reassigned to a different group.